# How to alter delay in a gif, without altering its speed

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

For stupid timing reasons, I need a gif that has delay 6. Alas, my material is delay 20.

What I effectively need is to drop delay to 6, and at the same time multiply every frame three or four times. I don't mind the timing being a little off.

This seems like a simple enough problem, but utterly ungoogelable.

Comment: If you are going to make up new words at least show some originality - I propose *"unGoogle-a-bubble"* :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Split animation into constituent frames, saving as "frame-nnn.gif"
convert animated.gif -coalesce frame-%03d.gif

# Make array of all framenames
frames=( frame-*gif )

# Triplicate array elements
for ((i=0;i<${#frames[@]};i++)); do newframes+="${frames[i]} ${frames[i]} ${frames[i]} "; done

# DEBUG echo ${newframes[@]}

# Rebuild animation with new speed
convert -delay 10 ${newframes[@]} new.gif

# Clean up
rm frame-*.gif 2> /dev/null
```

My script assumes your original is called `animated.gif` and the result will be called `new.gif`. Obviously you can change the delays and number of duplicates as you wish, the values I have chosen are illustrative.